# How can I build proper laplace RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks, laplace-transform

[image: problem]
I think there are two different circuits over the picture. But for equations they are acting same to me. I mean DC source of left circuit look like an initial voltage for C. After inver Laplace I have a capacitor voltage start with 40  even there's no initial voltage.

For the \$ R= 2 \$, \$ L= 20 \mu H \$ \$ C= 0.28 \mu F \$ \$ V=40 V \quad I0=14.55 A \$

Matlab ilaplace gave

\$ I(t)=14.55\rm{e}^{-50000t}(\cos{419608.6t}+0.208\sin{419608.6t})\$

To find Vc

\$ v_c(t)=\dfrac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{t} i(t) dt +C_0\$

and witout \$C_0\$ matlab int command gave this;

\$ V_c(t)=119.06\rm{e}^{-50000t}\sin{419608.6t}- 40 \rm{e}^{-50000t} \cos{419608.6t}\$

Now for left circuit \$C_0=0\$ But that means in the graph for \$t=0\$ Vc start with -40 V. İt looks wrong for me on the other hand i need add + or - 40V for \$ V_c(t)\$ but graph is more meaningful without adding  \$C_0\$

Comment: They are the same circuit.

Comment: Agreeing with @pgvoorhees, circuits are the same, therefore ODE are the same. Only initial condition is different.  *"I have a capacitor voltage start with 40 even there's no initial voltage."* Impossible. The voltage across a capacitor cannot change instantaneously. Please show your elaboration, so we can help you solving at the right point.

Comment: You're right I should be more clear. I edited my question